# Limit as $x$ tends to Infinity: Exponential vs $x^n$

Tags: limits

$$Y = (1 / x) + ln(x)$$

$y$ tends to infinity as x tends to infinity (by looking at the graph). Is this because ln is related to the exponential function, and the exponential function increases faster than any x^n function?

On the other hand,

$$Y = xe^{-1/x}$$

$y$ tends to plus infinity as x tends to plus infinity, and tends to negative infinity as x tends to negative infinity. How can this be explained?

Comment: No, this isn't because the exponential grows quickly. In fact, that's evidence *against* the limit being infinity - after all, $\tan x$ blows up in finite time (so it grows faster than $x^n$), but $\arctan x$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\ln(x)$$
When $x\to\infty$ :

- $\frac{1}{x}\to 0\quad$. Thus $y(x)$ behaves like $\quad 0+\ln(x)=\ln(x)$.
- $\ln(x) \to\infty\quad$. Thus $y(x)\to\infty$

Conclusion : $y(x)\to\infty$ because $\ln(x)\to\infty.\quad$Nothing more.
$$ $$
$$ $$

$$y(x)=xe^{-1/x}$$

When $x\to\pm\infty$ :

- $-1/x \to 0$
- $xe^{-1/x}$ behaves like $xe^0=x$

Conclusion : The same as $x\: ,\quad$  $xe^{-1/x}$  tends to $\begin{cases} +\infty \quad\text{when } x\to +\infty \\ -\infty \quad\text{when } x\to -\infty\end{cases}$

Comment: Makes complete sense - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first equation, note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\ln(x) = \infty$. Also $1/x$ is positive for all $x > 0$. Lastly, since $1/x$ and $\ln(x)$ are continuous for $x >0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1/x + \ln(x)) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}1/x + \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \ln(x)$. Therefore, the limit of $Y$ as $x$ goes to infinity is the sum of two positive numbers, one of which tends to infinity.